# Troubles with machine translation of a simple sentence

Tags: vocabulary

How come these three sentences have the same translation into English, yet they don't look very similar?

난 당신이 괜찮았으면 좋겠어.

나는 당신이 괜찮 으면 좋겠다.

괜찮으시길 바랍니다.

Sorry, I'm not a Korean learner, I just want to send this message to a younger friend of mine who also speaks English but I want them to feel better.

Answer (score 1):

They all sound like a translation of "I hope you are okay.".  They are grammatically correct but not what people are likely to say.  We would never say 당신 in that situation, for example, and 바랍니다 sounds too stiff to say to a friend.
괜찮았으면 좋겠어 can be said by itself in some cases.  If you're very close or if the other person is much younger you might say 네가 괜찮았으면 좋겠어, but otherwise you can leave the subject 네가 out.

You might say:

- 빨리 좋아졌으면 좋겠어 = I hope you get better soon.  (if they're down with illness).
- 별일 아니기를 바라 = I hope it is nothing serious.
- 지금 힘든 거 다 이겨낼 수 있어 = You can beat what's keeping your down now.

All these do not have the "you" in them, so they are only good when the subject of the message is about the other person, not yourself.  For example, you can say "How are you?" type of greeting first and say one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Those three sentences convey similar meanings but they have a little difference(feeling) each other.

- **난 당신이 괜찮았으면 좋겠어.**
  --> I want you to be okay.
  --> feels like focusing on your status and worrying about your sickness.
- **나는 당신이 괜찮 으면 좋겠다.**
  --> I'd like to edit this sentence to "나는 당신이 괜찮았으면 좋겠다." because the original sentence is quite awkward in ordinary cases because of spacing and vocabulary using. (it's almost the same as the first sentence.)
- **지금 힘든 거 다 이겨낼 수 있어.**
  --> You can beat everything that makes you hard/painful/sick/down.
  --> feel like encouraging and hoping you'll get better soon.

If you want to these messages to your younger friends, I recommend using the noun "너(informal/friendly, direct)" instead of "당신(formal)".

--> 나는 너가 괜찮았으면 좋겠어. (I want you to be okay.)
--> 너가 빨리 낫기를 바래.  (I hope you get well soon.)

I hope this answer would help you..